# Python sum it twice for groupby

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I'm struggling with a series sum after already grouped the dataframe, and I was hoping that someone could please help me with an idea. 
Basically I have in the example below I need to have the sum per each "Material". 
Basically Material "ABC" should give me 2, and all the others as they have only one sign operation would have the same value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    "Material" : ["M-12", "H4-LAMPE", "M-12", "H4-LAMPE",
                  "ABC" , "H4-LAMPE", "ABC", "ABC"] , 
    "Quantity" : [6, 1, 3, 5, 1, 1, 10, 9],
    "TYPE": ["+", "-", "+", "-", "+", "-", "+", "-"]})
df.groupby(['Material', "Quantity"], as_index=False).count()

listX = []
for item in df["TYPE"]:
    if item == "+":
        listX.append(1)
    elif item == "-":
        listX.append(-1)
    else:
        pass
df["Sign"] = lista
df["MovementsQty"] = df["Quantity"]*df["Sign"]
#df = df.groupby(["Material", "TYPE", "Quantity1"]).sum()
df1 = df.groupby(["Material", "TYPE"]).sum()
df1.drop(columns=["Quantity", "Sign"], inplace=True)

print(df1)
```

The result is:

[image]

The desired result is:

[image]

I tried to sum it again, to consider it differently but I was not successful so far and I think I need some help.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Presumably you don't need `Type` in your desired result, as the sign is already part of the net movements quantity.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track. I've tried to improve your code. Just use "Type" to determine and assign the sign using `np.where`, perform `groupby` and `sum`, and then re-compute the "Type" column based on the result.

```
v = (df.assign(Quantity=np.where(df.TYPE == '+', df.Quantity, -df.Quantity))
       .groupby('Material', as_index=False)[['Quantity']]
       .sum())

v.insert(1, 'Type', np.where(np.sign(v.Quantity) == 1, '+', '-'))
```

```
print (v)
   Material Type  Quantity
0       ABC    +         2
1  H4-LAMPE    -        -7
2      M-12    +         9
```

---

Alternatively, you can do this with two `groupby` calls:

```
i = df.query('TYPE == "+"').groupby('Material').Quantity.sum()
j = df.query('TYPE == "-"').groupby('Material').Quantity.sum()
# Find the union of the indexes.
idx = i.index.union(j.index)
# Reindex and subtract.
v = i.reindex(idx).fillna(0).sub(j.reindex(idx).fillna(0)).reset_index()
# Insert the Type column back into the result.
v.insert(1, 'Type', np.where(np.sign(v.Quantity) == 1, '+', '-'))

print(v)
   Material Type  Quantity
0       ABC    +       2.0
1  H4-LAMPE    -      -7.0
2      M-12    +       9.0
```

Comment: Dagnabbit!  You beat me to it. `df.assign(Quantity = np.where(df['TYPE'].eq('+'),df['Quantity'],-df['Quantity'])).groupby(['Material']).sum().pipe(lambda x: x.assign(TYPE = np.where(x.Quantity.lt(0),'-','+')))` I had a cool one-liner using `pipe`.

Comment: @coldspeed: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another take (fairly similar to coldspeed though).

```
#Correct quantity with negative sign (-) according to TYPE 
df.loc[df['TYPE'] == '-', 'Quantity'] *= -1

#Reconstruct df as sum of quantity to remove dups
df = df.groupby('Material')['Quantity'].sum().reset_index()
df['TYPE'] = np.where(df['Quantity'] < 0, '-', '+')

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   Material  Quantity TYPE
0       ABC         2    +
1  H4-LAMPE        -7    -
2      M-12         9    +
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `map` and `numpy.sign`

Just sum up `Quantity * TYPE` and figure out the sign afterwards.

```
d = {'+': 1, '-': -1}
r = dict(map(reversed, d.items())).get
q = df.Quantity
m = df.Material
t = df.TYPE

s = pd.Series((q * t.map(d)).values, m, name='MovementsQty').sum(level=0)
s.reset_index().assign(TYPE=lambda x: [*map(r, np.sign(x.MovementsQty))])

   Material  MovementsQty TYPE
0      M-12             9    +
1  H4-LAMPE            -7    -
2       ABC             2    +
```